# Flutter Sqlite read items from 1 column in db

Tags: flutter, sqlite

Im used to sql queries but im little confused how to get data from my database from one column. Here the example to get all items(include all columns):

```
 // Read all items (journals)
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    return db.query('items', orderBy: "id");
  }
```

In the database are few columns where one is named title. I did see something about rawQuery but i can not find any good examples of that, also i think that is not used much.

But what is the best way in the example above to get data from only the title column?

Comment: Add "columns: ['title']", according to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

return db.rawQuery("select title from items");

Answer (score 0):

No need to rawQuery to serve your task.
You can follow the below process.

`await db.query('yourTableName', columns: ["yourDesiredColumn"]);`

***Example based on your purpose.(Without rawQuery)***

`await db.query('yourTableName', columns: ["title"]);`

***Example based on your purpose.(With rawQuery)***

`await db.rawQuery('SELECT title FROM yourTableName');`